# Get value of umbraco datatype in code

Tags: c#, umbraco6

I have created a checkbox list type of data type in umbraco. see below screen shot
[image]

I am able to get the text value of this data type which is "All" in this case. But I am unable to get the Value in code.

```
umbraco.library.IProperty property = node.GetProperty("countries");
string val = property.Value;
```

I also looked at all the property fields but Value of this is not available.
Any one has any idea
I am using Umbraco 6.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you should be using the [GetPreValueAsString](https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/getprevalueasstring) for your soultion.

```
string val = umbraco.library.GetPreValueAsString(node.GetProperty<int>("countries"));
```